# Getting a single value with getJSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I´m learning to read json files with javascript . 
I made this simple test for the getJSON funcion

this is my external json file called data.json

```
{
 "data": [
   {"lat":42.35843,"lng":-71.05977, "label": "Boston" , "number": 21},
   {"lat":25.77427,"lng":-80.19366, "label": "Miami" , "number": 10},
   {"lat":37.77493,"lng":-122.41942, "label": "San Francisco", "number": 100},
   {"lat":-23.5475,"lng":-46.63611, "label": "San Paulo", "number": 60},
   {"lat":-12.04318,"lng":-77.02824, "label": "Lima", "number": 700},
   {"lat":21.30694,"lng":-157.85833, "label": "Honolulu", "number": 91},
   {"lat":-31.95224,"lng":115.8614, "label": "Perth", "number": 11},
   {"lat":-33.86785,"lng":151.20732, "label": "Sydney", "number": 41},
   {"lat":22.28552,"lng":114.15769, "label": "Hong Kong", "number": 521},
   {"lat":19.07283,"lng":72.88261, "label": "Mumbai", "number": 11},
   {"lat":30.06263,"lng":31.24967, "label":"Cairo", "number": 41},
   {"lat":-33.92584,"lng":18.42322, "label":"Ciudad del Cabo", "number": 21},
   {"lat":52.52437,"lng":13.41053, "label":"Berlin", "number": 54},
   {"lat":55.95206,"lng":-3.19648, "label":"Edimburgo", "number": 34},
   {"lat":55.75222,"lng":37.61556, "label":"Moscu", "number": 2}
 ]
}
```

and this is how I read the content

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script> 
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON('example.json', function (datos) {

      //this work   
      console.log(datos);

      //this not work   
      console.log(datos[0].number);
    }); 
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

the first console log is working , it shows the array object 
but when I try to log a single record of that array it gives me that error 
`Cannot read property 'number' of undefined`

it is something that I missing?

Comment: try   console.log(datos.data[0].number);

Comment: it works. Thank you.